# Shady Characters

Tags: java, concurrency, lambda, rags-to-riches

As part of my familiarization with the features of Java 8, and inspired by [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/63085/find-sum-of-number-of-times-that-each-character-of-source-occurs-in-the-target), I thought I would take the 'Shady Character' problem to 'the next level'.

The basic problem is that you have a 'source' string, and a target string. The objective is to count the number of characters in the target that also appear in the source.

I decided to clarify the problem in 1 way, and extend it in another:

1. If the source contains duplicate characters, they should only count once in the target.
2. The system should be able to count characters concurrently from multiple targets, and, additionally, should fully utilize as much processing capacity as possible, hopefully very efficiently.

Given that the objective was to use Java8 streams too, I specifically targeted the `IntStream` as an efficient way to handle the characters.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;


public class ShadyCharacters {

    private final boolean[] countIt;
    private final int offset;
    private final AtomicLong foundCount = new AtomicLong();

    public ShadyCharacters(final String source) {
        int min = Character.MAX_VALUE;
        int max = Character.MIN_VALUE;
        char[] chars = source.toCharArray();
        for (char c : chars) {
            min = Math.min(min, c);
            max = Math.max(max, c);
        }

        if (chars.length == 0) {
            offset = 0;
            countIt = new boolean[0];
        } else {
            offset = min;
            countIt = new boolean[max - min + 1];
            for (char c : chars) {
                countIt[c - offset] = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public long getCount() {
        return foundCount.get();
    }

    public long countShadows(final String target) {
        final long count = IntStream.range(0, target.length()).parallel()
            .map(charIndex -> target.charAt(charIndex) - offset)
            .filter(index -> index >= 0 && index < countIt.length && countIt[index])
            .count();
        foundCount.addAndGet(count);
        return count;
    }

    public void countShadows(final Collection<String> targets) {
        targets.parallelStream().forEach(target -> countShadows(target));
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ShadyCharacters schars = new ShadyCharacters("ardx");
        schars.countShadows("alex alexander");
        System.out.printf("Found %d shady characters%n", schars.getCount());

        String[] copies = new String[1000000];
        Arrays.fill(copies, "alex alexander");
        schars.countShadows(Arrays.asList(copies));
        System.out.printf("Found %d shady characters%n", schars.getCount());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess, I wouldn't bother with `min` as some "small" characters are always present. You're trying to conserve memory, but with `source` being `\u0000\uFFFF` you'll need 64 kB, anyway. No big deal and no nice and efficient way to avoid it.

Except for that you could reduce the memory consumption by a factor of 8 without much effort (but I don't tell you how :D:D:D). It'd surely reduce the speed a bit, so feel free top forget it.

```
private final AtomicLong foundCount = new AtomicLong();
```

You're aware that calling `countShadows` the second time return the sum of the first and second run? I found it confusing.

```
public long countShadows(final String target) {...}
public void countShadows(final Collection<String> targets) {...}
```

As both methods do about the same, they should both return `long` (or both `void`). I'd go for `long` and keep the class immutable.

I guess you need no `AtomicLong` at all. The streams are surely able to compute the sum themselves in a thread-safe way.

Comment: The countShadows could be called from many different threads, as well as being internally multi-threaded. Good observation about the countShadows(Collection) should also return long. BitSet was overkill, I thought :D

Comment: @rolfl Sure, it can be called from many thread, but I didn't recommend replacing `AtomicLong` by `long` or alike. I'd suggest to drop the state. Let the stream in the Collection method compute the sum and you're done. No state, no interference between different callers.

Comment: Sure is the `BitSet` an overkill. I just wanted to say, that's it's more effective than using `min` (unless dealing with very exotic strings).